# Is NodeJS supposed to be standalone (I.E. without apache nginx)

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

Ok so finally decided I was way behind in knowing some of the frameworks/platforms that are out like Angularjs, NodeJS, Knockout, Backbone etc etc. And so decided to learn NodeJS first, and have set it up on a local vm of ubuntu server.

So was wondering if NodeJS was supposed to be paired with another server software like apache,nginx, etc. And let apache/nginx just serve up the basic pages and then just let node do the data communications since their site says its  *"for easily building fast, scalable network applications"*.

Because I have seen several questions on S.O. asking how to get NodeJS to run on port 80, which implies they want to run node as a regular server or they just dont want to have to always specify a port when doing requests. And have not seen anyone comment or say that node was not meant to be used like a regular server. So was hoping to get to an answer on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node.js can be used standalone, out there are good frameworks to do it like [express](http://expressjs.com/). You can clusterize your process in the same physical machine (and the same port) really easy via its native module [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Also, I'm sure you can use Node.js like a reverse proxy too, but some developers prefer using other tools to do it (in my enterprise, we use Nginx with some of our node.js apps).

So, in short: You dont need Nginx or Apache at all, but you can use if you want. It's very cosy to some people use Nginx to do the load balance, or even other stuff like handle the https or server static content. It's your choice at the end.

You should play something with the native library [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or [https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) first, and then check express or another framework. You will see wich parts of Node.js you love and which do you dont feel awesome.